# Deleting intermediate record from Google Calendar recurring event

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am working with Google calendar recurring events. I created a recurring event and by using GData library, in response i get the the perimeters "COUNT", "FREQ" , "UNTIL" etc... where COUNT=5.

The problem is, when I delete an instance from this recurring event(total instance are 5 in this case), 4 instances are left in google calendar. but in response COUNT is still 5, it should be 4 now. Also in response i am not getting any details about that deleted instance.

Can any one help me in this regards.

I am very thankful in advance!!!

waiting for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as intended. If the count indeed changed that would mean that the last instance should not be there anymore. While you could have deleted the second instance. In the v3 API the deletion of the second instance will be represented by an event with status=cancelled and "recurringEventId" + "originalStartTime" set to point to that specific instance.

There is a handy instances() call if you want to see all the instances of a recurring event.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. yes you are right i am getting the deleted instance with status cancelled with important concatenated ID  "recurringEventId" + "originalStartTime"...

Comment: Dear i have another question please help me. i am stuck.  Question link is here                               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506679/how-to-delete-single-occurrence-of-recurring-event-using-zend-gdata