# How to delete single occurrence of recurring event using Zend_Gdata

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am working with Google calendar recurring events. I created a recurring event with ten instances, now by using Zend_Gdata i want to delete any single instance of this recurring event not the complete event.

The following line delete the complete recurring event.

$gdata->delete($feedEntry->getEditLink()->href);

But i want to delete only one instance ...

Can any one help me in this regards.

I am very thankful in advance!!!

waiting for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

I propose you migrate off GData as the API will be shut down in November (http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.ch/2014/06/calendar-gdata-api-google-calendar.html) and take a look at the v3 api (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/). Once on v3, you can delete an instance of a recurring event by calling a delete(instance.getId()) where you can retrieve the instance id using the instances() call.